# Explaination of incremental push's amortized time

Tags: algorithm-analysis

In the Narasimha's data structure book, there is a line

> The amortized time of a push operation in the incremental growth of array stack (realloc on every push) is $O(n) [O(n^2) / n]$.

I am confused with this Big-O notation here, what does it mean? Is arithmetic legal on big-o notation functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the amortized time complexity is $O(n)$, amortized over $n$ pushes. The $[O(n^2)/n]$ indicates that the $O(n)$ amortized time comes from a total time complexity of $O(n^2)$ divided by the $n$ pushes.

The total time complexity is $O(n^2)$ because a push in a stack of size $k$ costs $O(k)$, thus:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \ = \ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \ = \ O(n^2) \ . $$

Comment: Oh, is it something like $O\left(\frac{n^{\cancel{2}}}{\cancel{n}}\right) \to O(n)$ 

Comment: @tbhaxor yes, exactly

Comment: @SilivoM, I was under the impression that bigo functions does not support arithmetics. Thanks for this :D

Comment: @tbhaxor more or less...you have to be careful. When working with asymptotic notation keep always in mind what is the meaning of what you write. Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519347/arithmetic-rules-for-big-o-notation-little-o-notation-and-so-on